# UITableView not interacting after modyifing the bounds on a UIModalPresentationCustom

Tags: uitableview, ios8, uimodalpresentationstyle, uimodalpresentationcustom

Basically, I am trying to present a custom modal view with a specific size and position since I was able to manage this through popover on iOS 7. But on iOS it seems they change things.

I manage to achieve this with the following:

Presentation:

```
            UpViewController *upViewController = [[UpViewController alloc] init];
            upViewController.delegate = self;

            UINavigationController *navigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:upViewController];

            navigationController.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationCustom;

            [self presentViewController:navigationController animated:YES completion:nil];
```

In UpViewController.m:

```
- (void)viewWillLayoutSubviews
{
    [super viewWillLayoutSubviews];

    self.navigationController.view.superview.bounds = CGRectMake(-350, -30, 320, screenSize.height-(44+20));

}
```

My problem is after my modal view has been presented. We cannot interact with the UITableView that has been added to the view. Anyone has encounter this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems I found my own solution
instead of setting the bounds, I set the navigationController.view.frame:

```
- (void)viewWillLayoutSubviews
{
    [super viewWillLayoutSubviews];

    self.navigationController.view.frame = CGRectMake(screenSize.width-320, 44, 320, screenSize.height-(44));

}
```